# How do I reproject fits files using ccdproc's wcs_project?

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy, fits, ccdproc

I'm trying to stack a series of fits files. I was learning about the process, and I know that since they have distinct wcs, I have to adjust their orientation first, before I even begin to stack. I found ccdproc's `wcs_project` as a way to reasonably approach this. I was trying to follow the very last example on [this](https://ccdproc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/image_combination.html#reprojection) page. That being said, when I try to run the `wcs_project`, I keep getting an error with wcs.

My code is the following:

```
target_image = fits.open(list_of_fits_files[1])
target_wcs = WCS(target_image[0]).celestial

reprojected = []
for fits_file in list_of_fits_files:
    img = fits.open(fits_file)
    new_image = wcs_project(img, target_wcs)
    reprojected.append(new_image)
```

My error message is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-189-2f3f9f278991> in <module>
      9 for fits_file in list_of_fits_files:
     10     img = fits.open(fits_file)
---> 11     new_image = wcs_project(img, target_wcs)
     12     reprojected.append(new_image)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ccdproc/log_meta.py in wrapper(*args, **kwd)
     90         # Grab the logging keyword, if it is present.
     91         log_result = kwd.pop(_LOG_ARGUMENT, True)
---> 92         result = func(*args, **kwd)
     93 
     94         if not log_result:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ccdproc/core.py in wcs_project(ccd, target_wcs, target_shape, order)
    922     from reproject import reproject_interp
    923 
--> 924     if not (ccd.wcs.is_celestial and target_wcs.is_celestial):
    925         raise ValueError('one or both WCS is not celestial.')
    926 

AttributeError: 'HDUList' object has no attribute 'wcs'
```

What did I mess up? I've been trying to read up on ccdproc but there aren't many examples out there. Or if anyone suggests a better approach to stacking, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you wrote:

```
for fits_file in list_of_fits_files:
    img = fits.open(fits_file)
    new_image = wcs_project(img, target_wcs)
```

But the object returned by [`fits.open`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/api/files.html#astropy.io.fits.open) is an `HDUList` object (hence the error `AttributeError: 'HDUList' object has no attribute 'wcs'`), which is a list of the one or more HDUs stored in a single FITS file.  However, [`wcs_project`](https://ccdproc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/ccdproc.wcs_project.html#ccdproc.wcs_project) expects a [`CCDData`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.nddata.CCDData.html#astropy.nddata.CCDData) object, containing the actual image data (which may come from any source, which in your case happens to be a FITS file).

You can read a `CCDData` directly from a FITS file with [`CCDData.read('/path/to/image.fits')`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/nddata/index.html#reading-and-writing), so you probably want to write something like:

```
img = CCDData.read(fits_file)
new_image = wcs_project(img, target_wcs)
```

If your FITS file contains one image, `CCDData.read()` should be able to guess which image you want to load.  If it contains multiple images you may need to specify which extension to read; when reading from a FITS file `CCDData.read` takes all the same arguments as the lower-level function [`fits_ccddata_reader`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.nddata.fits_ccddata_reader.html#astropy.nddata.fits_ccddata_reader), e.g. for specifying the extension HDU to read from.  In most cases you won't need to do this though, depending on what the data is.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using astromatic software swarp (https://www.astromatic.net/software/swarp) to align the images first and then stack them.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which was about how to use the `ccdproc` package.